# Receiving TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class after updating python when importing langchain

Tags: python, python-3.x, homebrew, pyenv, langchain

I just updated langchain to 0.0.198 because it is the most recent version of langchain and has functions I'd like to use in my project. After updating though, I'm getting this error[vscode traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MalUX.png) for context im on mac and tried updating python to later versions but had to go back to 3.9.6 because no other version would work with anything I tried to import.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.